# Is it possible to get a lasing from every luminescent media?

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser

Let's assume that there is a cavity with a couple of mirrors and gain media between which possesses luminescence under some external excitation/pumping. Let the absolute quantum yield of the gain media be quite high - 50%, luminescence decay is approximately 100 µs and full width at half maximum is about 100 nm with maximum at 500 nm (something like blue-green light). All these parameters are quite real. So with such parameters what do we need to get lasing? And second question, what would the output spectrum look like?

Comment: For lasing you need a population inversion, which may not be achievable in all system. On the other hand, as a laser jock once told me, anything will lase if pumped hard enough (but that is because you will get non-linear effects, overcoming the issues causing the problem in the first sentence).

Comment: It's like with flying... you can make a barn door fly (I have seen that) or a lead cube (that I have not, but then, I have not been in the artillery), if you put a powerful enough engine on it. You don't need a cavity for a laser, either. The cavity is there to select a certain frequency, it's not essential for the amplification process. As for numerical predictions... that's not possible with your specifications. As Jon Custer said... one would need a level diagram of the system and a lot more information about the transitions.

Comment: In addition, in many cases luminescent emission goes down to the ground state, so absorption directly competes with stimulated emission.  That is, the medium itself has high losses that must be overcome.

Comment: @CuriousOne The cavity also provides feedback for oscillation.   The oscillation function and the frequency-filtering function are, of course closely related, but you can have a filter without the sustained oscillation.

Comment: @garyp: Just saying that it's a common misconception that one needs a cavity to have a laser. The laser is what's inside the cavity, the cavity itself is simply an optical filter that selects the frequency of interest.

Comment: @CuriousOne Technically, yes, but in common usage *laser* means a source of coherent radiation.  Take away the cavity and the usual terminology is *laser amplifier*.

Comment: @garyp: Like with most things in life common usage is technically mostly wrong. You can put two mirrors opposite each other and watch them until the cows come home... nothing, whatsoever, will happen.

Comment: garyp :curiousone is correct.   A reasonably long lasing medium will generate a coherent output if well-pumped.  It doesn't require a source oscillator as does a laser amp.

Comment: @garyp: As far as coherent radiation is concerned, that doesn't even require a laser. One can make very nicely spatially coherent radiation with a small aperture and temporally coherent radiation with optical filters or a simple gas discharge. The laser mechanism is very specific in that it produced a net optical gain, whether the source is coherent, or not, the laser amplifier would not care about that.

Comment: @garyp: You're right about the cavity. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Does the line width of your luminescence imply that there are many combinations of energy levels that give rise to emission, with similar transition probabilities between each?

Comment: @CuriousOne, et al.  Yes, I was too glib in my definition of *laser*.

Comment: @Floirs: it could be like you said, but it also can be a case when you have something like inhomogeneous broadening. For example, you can face it working with liquids and glass, but with crystals you defenitely wouldn't have such a broad line without different luminecent centers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Relevant link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227867/26969) - not exact duplicate . It discusses the need for population inversion, and how to achieve it. A system with fewer than three (four if you want to limit power loss) energy levels is unlikely to be able to sustain population inversion, so while you could get "stimulated emission" it's unlikely that the output of such a medium would be coherent (there would be too many opportunities for spontaneous emission that destroy the coherence).

Comment: Well, ok. That's fair. But if you noticed, I've pointed out that the luminecence decay time is 100 mks, which is quite long and means that we deal with phosphorescence and at least three lavel scheme. So it might be that I didn't emphasise that but my question is beyond the simple two level case. If your answer is still "the need for population inversion", that fine. But I wondered if there is something else

Comment: To be honest I skipped over that detail. I am not familiar with the abbreviation `mks` - milli kilo seconds sounds wrong. Can you please explain? Your title question was "every luminescent media", but you seem to be asking about a specific medium.

Comment: yes, sorry. I mean microseconds

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's not exactly "every luminecent media", but in my experiance it's quite common parameters for liquids and solids that are able to glow, so that's why I discribed it like this

Comment: @ДмитрийКлюкин: What we are trying to say is that fluorescence alone is not enough to build a practical laser. Useful laser materials need very specific mechanisms to get the higher energy level of a pair of fluorescent states to be populated more strongly than the lower. This can be achieved in many ways (setting off a nuclear weapon was very popular with president Reagan, for instance, even though the physics of x-ray lasers made that way still sucks so badly that even that doesn't work well), but unless the material is chosen well, it won't show nice laser properties.

Comment: @CuriousOne: thanks, for your comment. It's very nice, but when you're talking about "specific mechanisms", that's exactly what I'm asking about. I'm just curious whether it is only a question of pumping power or not? For me it seems like one can increase the decay time from exited state and that'd be enough, but it still could be beaten by increasing the pumping power. In this way Jon Custer's friend is right. And of course we're not talking about any preactical laser, just the posibility to get lasing some lumiencent media.

Comment: @ДмитрийКлюкин: Yes, it is only a matter of engine power to get something to fly. Does that mean you want to fly to New York in a lead ball "pumped" by a giant cannon? Would you not rather prefer a well built passenger airplane with airfoils optimized so well that the plane can fly smoothly with the least amount of engine power? I would suggest that you read up on the theory of three level lasers. That should explain why a two-level system is a bad way to start your day as a laser engineer... unless you can supply some resonant or brute force population mechanism.

Comment: @CuriousOne - if you read the answer I linked you would see that three level lasers, while possible, require pumping from the ground state - and therefore you need at least half of all atoms excited to have a shot at population inversion - that's the cannon ball. You need four levels for a "decent shot" - a comfortable passenger plane.

Comment: @CuriousOne: well, yes, I got it. It seems like you're talking about engeneering and I'm talking about science. Anyway, your words make sence.

Comment: @ДмитрийКлюкин: I am talking about the physical working principles of lasers. What you are giving us is the information about a two-level system and it takes a three level system to build an optically pumped laser. If you don't want to pump optically, then you can use two levels, but you need a second atomic or molecular species that can transfer the energy to your luminescing molecules or you have to use e.g. ionizing radiation to pump.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I've explained it to Floris earlier. I'm talking about at least three level system as long as a time decay is microseconds. In two level system you would have a time decay approximately several nanosecond for any atom. Sorry that I didn't mentione it in the beginning

Comment: @ДмитрийКлюкин: Why would the decay time be indicative of the number of levels involved????

Comment: @CuriousOne because it's quite long for any two level system. That's why I gave this number for example

Comment: @ДмитрийКлюкин: I am not aware of any such restrictions. Is this a rule of thumb for certain classes of chemical dyes?

Comment: @CuriousOne yes, it's about singlet-singlet and singlet-triplet transmissions. Triplet-singlet transition takes much more time

Comment: @ДмитрийКлюкин: Again, I have never heard of such general "rules". I can, indeed, think of quantum systems that take billions of years for a transition... Can you give a citation?

Comment: @CuriousOne: here is a [link](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy%3A_Theory)